# What does `static PyObject * spam_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)` declare?

Tags: c

I'm new to `C` programming language. 
I'm aware of `function` declaration:

```
// declaring function
void getMax();
```

As well as `pointer`:

```
//declaring pointer to char
char *p
```

But could you give me the cue what is declared
 with a combination of the above two syntax constructs:

```
static PyObject * spam_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
//some code here
}
```

?

Comment: Do you know what function parameters are? Looks like you need a good book.

Comment: Please don't tag C++ on C questions. They are very different languages.

Comment: @molbdnilo
Thanks, i won't!

Comment: @SombreroChicken, I was sure that I know what it is

Comment: If you dig into Python extensions, you're going to get more confused very soon. Don't get discouraged by that – you need to know a lot about both C in general and the implementation of Python, and a beginner is not expected to understand most of them.

Comment: @molbdnilo, yeah, i didn't used to static typing yet. Thank you for understanding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> static PyObject * spam_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)

It's a definition of a static function called `spam_system`, returning a pointer to a `PyObject` and taking two parameters, `self` and `args`, both are pointers to `PyObject`.

What does it mean, if a function is static? A static function is a function that is only visible to other functions in the same [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29).

Comment: Small correction: only visible "in the same _translation unit_" which is not necessarily the same as "in the same _file_".